# dnf.exceptions.error some packages from local repository have incorrect checksum

Tags: linux, virtualbox, rhel

I am trying to install redhat (rhel8) in virtualBox 6.1 on a windows 10 64 bit Home edition machine.
I verified the checksum of the iso file after download and its correct (I compared the checksum against another friend iso file who is able to install properly), still I am getting exception like
**dnf.exceptions.error some packages from local repository have incorrect checksum** 
[image]

I even tried to run troubleshooting, but it raise exceptin like
**failed to start media check on /dev/sr0 virtualbox**
I have downloaded the iso files from multiple places and every time it gives me the same exception.
Any help is highly aprreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the reason for the above error.

---

Virtual Box uses virtualization to run multiple Operating Systems and in one system (let's say a windows machine) only one of the application will be allowed to use system virtualization capability.
So we have to disable any manual virtualization if performed in the system.

### So we can disable virtualization by following ways:

- Search for “Turn Windows features on or off” in the Start menu, hit
  the Enter key to open the Windows Features window. Here, scroll down
  to Hyper-V and disable it by clearing checkbox next to it. Then click
  OK

[image]

- Disable Hyper-V by using command.

Press Windows logo key + X, then hit A to run Command Prompt as administrator. In Command Prompt window, type

---

`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

---

and hit Enter key to execute this command.
[image]

Finally restart system.